# What is the best data structure in java for saving Bigdata Integer records?

Tags: java, data-structures, bigdata

I am working with massive graphs and i need to save the records of them in memory.I have aboat `1,000,000,000` records That consist of Integers. The records are:

```
record1: 13455659009,2459904444, 888999, 45590008
record2: 7787687970097,98776,898767746,6556
........
record1000000000:  8736406,.....,987586985,764765282
```

first i used bitset to save them, forexample for record1 i did this:

```
BitSet bs=new BitSet();
bs.set(134659009);
bs.set(245990444);
bs.set(888999);
bs.set(45590008);
```

but bitset is not efficient. because i have only four numbers but it saves 245990444.
I want to save these records in ram, so it is important to occupy less space. what is the best structure to save these integer records in ram?
Is hashset better than bitset
Thanks.?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient structure would probably be a primitive integer array, that is `int[]`.  Depending on how you're using it, it may (or may not) be helpful to wrap it with a class that implements `java.lang.Set<Integer>`.

On the other hand, why do you even need an integer list of graph node IDs?  Why not just a `Node` class, and a `Set<Node>` member of it for the graph edges?

Comment: I need to store adjacancy list for each node. I have a hashtable that the key is node id and the value is record of its adjacancy list.

Comment: If you have a billion vertices and four or five edges for each vertex, the most memory-efficient way to store them is probably as a raw `int[]` array (in your hash value). Even that will by something like 30 GB for all those arrays.  You'll also save some memory (assuming most of the vertices have edges) with an array instead of a hashtable, that is `int[][]` rather than `HashMap<Integer,BitSet<Integer>>`.